# COUNTIFS unpredictably returns Zero

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup, spreadsheet, countif

I am trying to grab advertising expenses for the day on the basis of country groups.
The date, and country for the record are in columns I, J and G respectively.
[image]

I am doing a VLOOKUP that references a sheet called advertising,
with the search key being a date and month together, and picking up the value column based on the country.
[image][image]
Then in order to average it out, I am dividing this lookup, which gives me the ad spend for a set of countries by the number of records for that date, month and country.

```
=(IF(OR(G4="Spain",G4="Portugal"),VLOOKUP(I4&J4,Advertising!$A$3:$AK,32,0)*IF(COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Spain","Portugal"})>0,1/COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Spain","Portugal"}),0),
IF(G4="France",VLOOKUP(I4&J4,Advertising!$A$3:$AK,33,0)*IF(COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"France"})>0,1/COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"France"}),0),
IF(G4="Italy",VLOOKUP(I4&J4,Advertising!$A$3:$AK,34,0)*IF(COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Italy"})>0,1/COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Italy"}),0),
IF(OR(G4="Belgium",G4="Netherlands"),VLOOKUP(I4&J4,Advertising!$A$3:$AK,35,0)*IF(COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Belgium","Netherlands"})>0,1/COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Belgium","Netherlands"}),0),
IF(G4="Sweden",VLOOKUP(I4&J4,Advertising!$A$3:$AK,36,0)*IF(COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Sweden"})>0,1/COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Sweden"}),0),
IF(G4="United Kingdom",VLOOKUP(I4&J4,Advertising!$A$3:$AK,37,0)*IF(COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"United Kingdom"})>0,1/COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"United Kingdom"}),0),
VLOOKUP(I4&J4,Advertising!$A$3:$AK,31,0)*IF(COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Germany","Austria","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Australia","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Norway","Romania","Russia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Switzerland","UAE"})>0,1/COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Germany","Austria","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Australia","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Norway","Romania","Russia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Switzerland","UAE"}),0)
)))))))
```

Unfortunately, this is returning an error for me.

As you can see, I have an IF clause to avoid division by zero.

However, I have somehow convinced myself that the error is being reurned in the averaging (i.e. division with the COUNTIFS) process, not in the VLOOKUP. I do believe my COUNTIFS are illegitimately and unexplainably returning zero.

e.g. for row 4 in the main sheet, which I have posted above,

```
=COUNTIFS(I$4:I,I4,J$4:J,J4,G$4:G,{"Germany","Austria","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Australia","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Norway","Romania","Russia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Switzerland","UAE"})
```

returns a zero. When I test it out with fewer countries, always including Austria, sometimes it returns zero, sometimes 1.

A sample sheet is at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YgK_D7FaTWtKcSts2uDiG7jlTRx2_IGrJ41wZr2qyak/edit?usp=sharing

P.S. I do not have enough reputation, but I would request one of the seniors to add "countifs" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in row 4:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I4:I&"×"&J4:J, 
 {Advertising!B3:B&"×"&Advertising!C3:C, Advertising!B3:AK}, 
 MATCH(G4:G, Advertising!A1:1, ), )))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I4:I&"×"&J4:J, 
 {Advertising!B3:B&"×"&Advertising!C3:C, Advertising!AE3:AK}, MATCH(IFNA(VLOOKUP(G4:G, 
 {{"France";"Germany";"Austria";"Bulgaria";"Croatia";"Cyprus";"Australia";"Denmark";"Estonia";"Finland";"Greece";"Hungary";"Ireland";"Latvia";"Lithuania";"Luxembourg";"Malta";"Norway";"Romania";"Russia";"Slovakia";"Slovenia";"Switzerland";"UAE";"Italy";"Belgium";"Netherlands";"Spain";"Portugal";"Sweden";"United Kingdom"}, 
  {"France";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Italy";"Netherlands";"Netherlands";"Spain";"Spain";"Sweden";"United Kingdom"}},
 2, )), Advertising!AD1:AK1, 0), ))/
 COUNTIFS(I4:I&"×"&J4:J&IFNA(VLOOKUP(G4:G, 
 {{"France";"Germany";"Austria";"Bulgaria";"Croatia";"Cyprus";"Australia";"Denmark";"Estonia";"Finland";"Greece";"Hungary";"Ireland";"Latvia";"Lithuania";"Luxembourg";"Malta";"Norway";"Romania";"Russia";"Slovakia";"Slovenia";"Switzerland";"UAE";"Italy";"Belgium";"Netherlands";"Spain";"Portugal";"Sweden";"United Kingdom"}, 
  {"France";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Italy";"Netherlands";"Netherlands";"Spain";"Spain";"Sweden";"United Kingdom"}}, 
 2, )), I4:I&"×"&J4:J&IFNA(VLOOKUP(G4:G, 
 {{"France";"Germany";"Austria";"Bulgaria";"Croatia";"Cyprus";"Australia";"Denmark";"Estonia";"Finland";"Greece";"Hungary";"Ireland";"Latvia";"Lithuania";"Luxembourg";"Malta";"Norway";"Romania";"Russia";"Slovakia";"Slovenia";"Switzerland";"UAE";"Italy";"Belgium";"Netherlands";"Spain";"Portugal";"Sweden";"United Kingdom"},
  {"France";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Germany";"Italy";"Netherlands";"Netherlands";"Spain";"Spain";"Sweden";"United Kingdom"}}, 
 2, )))))))
```

[image]

---

or like this:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I4:I&"×"&J4:J, 
 {Advertising!B3:B&"×"&Advertising!C3:C, Advertising!AE3:AK}, 
 MATCH(IFNA(VLOOKUP(G4:G, Sheet3!A:B, 2, )), Advertising!AD1:AK1, 0), ))/
 COUNTIFS(I4:I&"×"&J4:J&IFNA(VLOOKUP(G4:G, Sheet3!A:B, 2, )),   
          I4:I&"×"&J4:J&IFNA(VLOOKUP(G4:G, Sheet3!A:B, 2, )))))))
```

[image]

Comment: @OC2PS answer and your sheet updated

Comment: You madam/sir are a scholar and a treasure. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `match()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      I4:I & J4:J, 
      { Advertising!B3:B & Advertising!C3:C, Advertising!B3:AK }, 
      match(G4:G, Advertising!A1:AK1, 0), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YgK_D7FaTWtKcSts2uDiG7jlTRx2_IGrJ41wZr2qyak/edit#gid=943909964) sheet in your sample spreadsheet. The formula is in cell `P4`.

Note that not all the country names in your search keys are present in the data.

Comment: Thanks! It's not quite there yet. P5 and P6 need to be 9.62 each, for example. The column headers in Advertising (AE1:AK1) represent groups of countries and aren't actual countries to be referenced. e.g. Spain in Adversitng sheet represents Spain and Portugal. Germany represents Germany, Austria, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Australia...